# Interpose C function defined as function pointer inside a structure

Tags: c, macos, dyld, function-interposition

Good morning,

Is it possible, using dyld interposition feature, to interpose this kind of C function ?

```
typedef struct aStructure {
    IOReturn (*aCfunction)(void *self, UInt32 integer); // self is a 
                                                        // pointer to aStructure
} aStructure;
```

How the function is called:

```
aStructure **myStruct = ......;

(*myStruct)->aCfunction(myStruct, 1);
```

Comment: have you figured this out? i have similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535716/interpose-c-struct-function-pointer-macos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably only possible if you can figure out where the actual function is, and interpose *that*.

There will be code to initialize the function pointer field in the structure to point at an actual function and I guess that's where you need to change things.

Also, you calling line is slighly off, it needs to be

```
(*myStruct)->aCfunction(*myStruct, 1);
```

Comment: after some gdb magic, it appears that these C function pointers are wrappers for C++ methods. It's going to be easier now. Nonetheless, I'm right about the function call (I follow Apple docs )