# Interpose C struct function pointer

Tags: c++, c, macos

i'm trying to interpose function declared as a pointer in a C struct inside dynamic library on macOS.

I have this struct in libA.dylib:

libA.h:

```
typedef struct AStruct {
    int (*sub)(AStruct *pAStruct, int a, int b);
} AStruct;

extern "C" AStruct * AStruct_new();
```

libA.cpp:

```
int sub(AStruct *pAStruct, int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

AStruct * AStruct_new() {
    AStruct *pAStruct = (AStruct *)malloc(sizeof(AStruct));
    pAStruct->sub = *sub;
    return pAStruct;
}
```

after name mangling, i've figured out that corresponding name in library is this: `_Z3subP7AStructii`

inside my dylib (which i'm injecting into a client code) i'm doing this:

```
typedef struct AStruct {
    int (*sub)(AStruct *pAStruct, int a, int b);
} AStruct;

extern "C" int _Z3subP7AStructii(AStruct *pAStruct, int a, int b);

int _sub(AStruct *pAStruct, int a, int b) {
    printf("interposed %s: ", __func__);
    return pAStruct->sub(pAStruct, a, b);
} DYLD_INTERPOSE(_sub, _Z3subP7AStructii)
```

`DYLD_INTERPOSE` - is Apple's macro from [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-97.1/include/mach-o/dyld-interposing.h.auto.html)

the same code successfully works for regular C function, C++ static/instance methods, can't figured out what's wrong with function pointer inside struct :(

Comment: Not related to question: try: `extern "C" int sub(....` to avoid name mangling (although *sub* is kind of a common name).

Comment: the point is that i cann't control code in libA, it's only an example :(

Comment: There are also other problems, like you seemingly copying the struct `AStruct` into your own code, which makes it vulnerable because if there's even one character mismatch between your structure and the structure in `libA` then you'll have *undefined behavior* as you break the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). And that mismatch could be even a single space.

Comment: it works with regular C functions, and C++ methods, can't understand what i'm doing wrong in this demo with struct function pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all calls to `sub` (or rather `_Z3subP7AStructii`) to actually be calling your `_sub` function instead? The problem is that when the "client" calls `some_astruct->sub(...)` it doesn't actually call `_Z3subP7AStructii` directly, and therefore your `_sub` function won't be called.

In other words, the "client" doesn't have a call to `_Z3subP7AStructii`, but instead it have a call to whatever `some_astruct->sub` is pointing to. The `_Z3subP7AStructii` function could even not be exported by the `libA` library (i.e. have internal linkage with e.g. `static`), and it could still be called through the structure.

A possible solution to this is not to "interpose" the `sub` function, but instead the `AStruct_create` function. In your version call the original, then replace the pointer to the `sub` function in the structure to your own function (possibly saving the original so you can use it).